# Partial derivative of a function of several variables in Maplesoft Maple

Tags: maple

I have a function of several variables,

```
W := (x__A, x__B, x__C, lambda, mu) -> 25*x[A]^2 + 100*x[B]^2 - lambda(6*x__A + 11*x__B + 4*x__C - E__P) - mu(x__A + x__B + x__C - 1)
```

However, when I try to find the partial derivative of the function W with respect to x_A, I am getting

```
-6*D(lambda)(6*x__A + 11*x__B + 4*x__C - E__P) - D(mu)(x__A + x__B + x__C - 1)
```

However, the answer is supposed to be `∂W/∂xA=50x_A - 6λ - μ`. Below is the MWE showing my code and the undesired output:

```
> W := (x__A, x__B, x__C, lambda, mu) -> 25*x[A]^2 + 100*x[B]^2 - lambda(6*x__A + 11*x__B + 4*x__C - E__P) - mu(x__A + x__B + x__C - 1)

> diff(W(x__A, x__B, x__C, lambda, mu), x__A)
```

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there are some typos in your definition of `W`.

There should be multiplication symbols between names and the opening brackets, otherwise you're denoting *function applications* of `lambda` and `mu` instead of *products of terms* (assuming you're intending the brackets as subexpression separators, to group terms).

Also, you use `x__A` and `x__B` in the left hand-side of the definition, but you use `x[A]` and `x[B]` at two places in the right hand-side. Both render as subscripted items when pretty-printed as output, but they are different things.

So, adjusting those we get,

```
W := (x__A,x__B,x__C,lambda,mu) -> 25*x__A^2 + 100*x__B^2
                                   - lambda*(6*x__A + 11*x__B + 4*x__C - E__P)
                                   - mu*(x__A + x__B + x__C - 1):
```

Now, how to differentiate? We can perform a *functional* differentiation of *operator* `W` with respect to its *first argument* as follows:

```
D[1](W);

  (x__A,x__B,x__C,lambda,mu) -> 50*x__A-6*lambda-mu
```

Note that -- similar to `W` itself -- the result is also an operator.

You could also call `W` with names as arguments, and then differentiate that resulting *expression*.

```
diff(W(x__A,x__B,x__C,lambda,mu), x__A);

       50 x__A - 6 lambda - mu
```

Note that doing so worked, but then there's little point to defining `W` as an operator; you could more simply have assigned it as the resulting expression. Ie,

```
W := 25*x__A^2 + 100*x__B^2
 - lambda*(6*x__A + 11*x__B + 4*x__C - E__P)
 - mu*(x__A + x__B + x__C - 1):

diff(W, x__A);

       50 x__A - 6 lambda - mu
```